# Joomla Mass Mails not working, SMTP settings ok

Tags: joomla-2.5, emails, smtp

I'm trying to use Joomla's Mass Mail function to test emails being sent from Joomla and a contact form plugin (Fox Contact). When trying to send an email using the Mass Mail form, Joomla shows the error `The following from address failed: noreply@mydomain.com` (noreply@mydomain.com is the SMTP username and from address).

I have confirmed the SMTP details are correct in Site > Global Configuration > Server Configuration > Mail Settings I have also tested the configuration using a telnet connection from the web server, which is able to send emails after authenticating using the username and password in Joomla.

I then tried to enable SMTP debugging by editing `~/libraries/phpmailer/phpmailer.php` and changing `$SMTPDebug` from `false` to 2. However this does not show any additional output (other than the above `address failed` message).

How can I fix the SMTP sending, or enable debugging to find the cause of the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem, the server had the `fsockopen()` function disabled for security, which PHPMailer 2.1.4 (included with Joomla 2.5) uses. The issue was not present on Joomla 3.5 sites, as these use PHPMalier 2.1.14, which does not use this function.

Removing the function from the `disabled_functions` section of php.ini restored the email functionality to all Joomla 2.5 sites. Still a bit strange how there was no error message though.

Answer (score 1):

There 2 things to check: 
first of all is email count registration is completed - some services requests additional data filled at account before it can send email (spent 5 hours to find this issue once)
second - is there right authentication protocol chosen in Joomla mail server configuration